# Automatically saving images into a folder with user defined name

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an image without any name and I want to directly save this image in a specific folder with default name(image1, image2, and so on.....) 
As of  now I am using this code to manually save the images.

```
   if (imageOpened == true)
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "PNG Files(*.png)|*.png";

            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                imagePanelControl.SaveImage(sfd.FileName);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Load a file before saving!");

        imagePanelControl.Invalidate();
    }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Where is original image comes from?(is in picture box?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to find out what we need:
First we need to find all files witch matches pattern "image{ONE or MORE DIGIT}.png", so:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"image(\d)+[.]");
var list = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.png").Where(path => reg.IsMatch(path)).ToList();
```

Check if any file exist, if yes return "image1.png", the code is: `if (list.Count == 0) return "image1.png";`

Last step is to find the last number, so we have to remove everything from files in list except the number, order the list, and take last. The code is following:

```
list.Select(x => (new FileInfo(x)).Name.Replace("image", "").Replace(".png", "")).OrderBy(x => x).Last();
```

The last step is to parse above value and add one. The final code is:

```
        private static string GetNewFileName(string dir)
        {
            Regex reg = new Regex(@"image(\d)+[.]");

            var list = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.png").Where(path => reg.IsMatch(path))
                     .ToList();

            if (list.Count == 0)
                return "image1.png";

            var lastName =
                list.Select(x => (new FileInfo(x)).Name.Replace("image", "").Replace(".png", "")).OrderBy(x => x).Last();

            return string.Format("image{0}.png", int.Parse(lastName)+1);
        }
```

;